# Using JSF RequestScoped Bean for Confirmation Page

Tags: java, jsf, backing-beans

I have a JSF page that loads a User and allows me to assign Roles to that particular User.  The Backing Bean, `AssignRolesBean` is `@RequestScoped`, and I would like for it to remain so.  However, here's my problem...

When the form submits, it calls `AssignRolesBean.execute()`.  This then returns the path to the confirmation page.  On this confirmation page, I want to show what new roles will be assigned and which role will be removed.  However, I'm having trouble getting the User loaded on the confirmation page.

On the initial AssignRoles page, the userId is set using a GET parameter.  It is then added as an `h:inputHidden` element on the page.  It does get submitted.  But, again, on the next page, the userId is not set (which loads the User).  Is there any way I can keep the RequestScope and not have to store the userId in the SessionMap?  I've been told that using hidden inputs will allow you to take data across pages.  But, I'm having trouble with that.

Answer (score 1):

if you develop jsf2 app, you can use flash scope to pass the parameters. 
For more information about flash scope you can look at [Learning JSF2: Using Flash scope](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-using-flash-scope/)

or you can put the parameters into session map

code snippet to get sessionMap:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your view to execute an action upon a GET request:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

with

```
public void init() {
    // Request parameters which are set by h:inputHidden, @ManagedProperty
    // or f:viewParam are available here.
    // You can just do e.g:
    this.user = userService.find(userId);
}
```